# How to model this case in DDD?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm facing the issue where either I can't apply DDD, or the case can't be reformulated to fit the DDD rules.

**The requirements:**

1. We have a `Product` and `Location`.
2. Change in `Location` should be reflected in `Product` which user then sees. Therefore `Product` references `Location`.
3. Same `Location` might be used in several `Products`.
4. `Product` might be created and deleted at any time point.
5. `Location` might be created at any time point.
6. `Location` might be deleted only if there is no `Product` references this `Location`.
7. Delete of a `Product` does not lead to `Location` deletion.

There are two more entities in the model exist with the same rules as `Location`, but solution should be the same as with `Location` case.

*Clarification 1*:

`Product` can't exist without being in any `location`, or without being related to any `location`, it MUST have a location. You might create both aggregates in any time point, but condition to create `Product` is having a `Location` already exist.

**My thoughts:**

So the problem which I see, that such requirements creates circular dependency on `Product` and `Location`. Because they all have own unlimited life cycle they supposed to be separate aggregation roots, but then this violates the consistency boundary, as basically one AR is trying to control another AR. So, this invariant can't be placed in any of those two. Trying to extract this into third one on the top AR also not clear how this would work.

**The question:**

How can I satisfy such requirements in DDD? Removing the constraint 6 is not an option. I've already tried to negotiate this with business side.

Comment: https://udidahan.com/2009/01/24/ddd-many-to-many-object-relational-mapping/ Maybe this helps in your case. Looks like DDD does not like n:m relationships.

Comment: @inf3rno, Well. Looks relevant, but still, I can not come up with good business scenario of failure for this model to either remove requirement 6, or to change the model completely.
Or, it's not DDD then, but what it is then?)

Comment: I think when the rules don't cover your case, then you should violate them.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregates are consistency boundaries.  So if you absolutely need changes to any location to be immediately reflected in products, and vice versa, then you basically need to have all locations and all products in a single aggregate and then have some form of concurrency control which effectively limits how that mega-aggregate changes (and will dramatically limit the rate at which this mega-aggregate can change).

Note that you can use infrastructure (e.g. relational DB transactions with foreign key requirements) to pretend that what's really one mega-aggregate is multiple smaller aggregates.  Going this way doesn't change the fundamental performance (it's likely to have a much higher ceiling than the key-value optimistic concurrency control approach that a simple DDD implementation will use because it will allow concurrent updates to disparate parts of the mega-aggregate) and has the downside of instead of your domain logic living in one place in your code, it's now partially encoded in your DB schema (whether or not it's duplicated elsewhere in your code).

It's not really accurate to say that DDD (specifically aggregates) can't be applied or that a case doesn't fit the rules around aggregates, any more than one can say that the laws of physics can't be applied.  It's just that the solution you get to when applying the requirements is not one you like.

Or it's possible that the requirements are mutually incompatible (e.g. a requirement to be able to perform X updates in some period of time with strong consistency).  This is where refining requirements may be helpful, specifically around loosening consistency requirements.  It's really common for a stronger consistency requirement to be assumed than the domain actually requires (asking questions like, "what actually happens if this happens..." is helpful).

Comment: I thought about single aggregate in this case, but it's not clear how to do it. As I'll have additional two entities with the same behaviour as location, and then what? I still would need to provide access to separate aggregates.

Comment: What do you mean not clear how to do it?  In the worst case, you have an aggregate that has a map of every location, every product, etc.

Comment: The aggregate root in that case doesn't really matter because that aggregate is a singleton.

Comment: What can we do instead of using aggregates in these n:m relationship cases? As far as I understand it is sort of linking things together and broken link does not necessarily hurt much. It just means you cannot see the product location or the products for a certain location. Things like this happen every day.

Answer (score 1):

This all looks pretty straight forward; your data model for "product" includes a link (a name, an identifier, etc) to a "location".

The only tricky bit is:

> Location might be deleted only if there is no Product references this Location.

You should probably review Udi Dahan: [Don't Delete - Just Don't](https://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/).

---

Important question: what's the cost to the business of a failure here?

If having products with deleted locations is expensive, then you have to design your data model with that constraint in mind.  That probably means you are going to have to lock your product data when deleting locations, and maybe also locking locations when updating products.

At a guess, you're probably going to be looking at storing all products and locations in the same database, and setting up foreign key constraints to ensure that the rules are followed.  Yes, there might be a performance penalty because of this sort of design, but that's justified by the fact that it solves an expensive problem.

On the other hand, if the business is a bit more forgiving, then there may be other ways of thinking about the domain model.  One possibility is that Location has "state" - being either active or deprecated, where product processing is not permitted to assign products to deprecated locations (deprecated locations would be hidden from the dropdown), but the deprecated locations still appear in reports.

(In effect, we're talking about a form of soft delete here, but at the level of our actual business processes, rather than down in the plumbing.)

---

It might help to expand your understanding of "Location" in the business - is Location a concept where this domain model is the Source Of Truth? or are instead Locations a form of reference data?  Do locations arise out of some data import / data entry process, or are they something produced by your domain model.

In the [Cargo Shipping](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/tree/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/model/cargo) example from the original DDD book, locations are really reference data; the actual list of international ports and terminals is [managed by UN/ECE](https://unece.org/trade/uncefact/unlocode), with updates being issued twice a year.

Therefore, in modeling a shipping domain, we'd be expecting location codes to appear via a data import process.  Note that "delete" here has a lot of latency built into it - the national authority decides a location should be delisted, and that needs to be processed by UN/ECE, and that means that the next issue that goes out reports that the code is *marked for deletion*; and various processes in place to ensure that the code in question is not re-used for some extended period of time after being "deleted".

Any sort of "immediate consistency" requirement here would be absurd, given that it takes months for the information to move through the system.  There has to be room in the domain model for local decisions to be made without waiting on decisions made elsewhere.

On the other hand, if you are creating a location model for UN/ECE, which is itself the Source of Truth for code assignments, then stricter consistency requirements might be appropriate.

Horses for courses.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately your answer sounds  more like, try again change the business requirements. I don't agree with a don't delete article, no matter how you call it it's still about dealing with state transition of an aggregate. And I would need to prevent location deletion when there is a product refs, or location "cancelation" <set here any word> when there is a product refs to this location.

Answer (score 0):

In your point number 2, you say

> Change in Location should be reflected in Product which user then sees. *Therefore Product references Location.*

I don't think this conclusion is correct. The way I see it, the Product does not need to know about locations, or at least, you haven't mentioned any rule that requires that. The fact that the user needs to see the Product location means that you need a way to query locations based on Product Ids, but that's a query issue, not an aggregate issue. The aggregate vs query distinction becomes apparent if you follow CQRS.

You can design a Location Aggregate that keeps a collection of Products. These products in the Location aggregate won't be actual Product Aggregates, but entities with a ProductId plus potentially other properties.

Let's look at your rules:

> Same Location might be used in several Products.

This is solved by having a collection of Products in the Location aggregate

> Product might be created and deleted at any time point.

A Product can exist without being in any location.

When a product is deleted, you'll need to publish an event so that all locations that contain that product can remove it (that would also require a way of finding Location aggregates referencing ProductIds)

> Location might be created at any time point.

No problem. A Location can exist without referencing any products.

> Location might be deleted only if there is no Product references this Location.

This is now easy to implement as the Delete operation in Location aggregate can check its Products collection.

> Delete of a Product does not lead to Location deletion.

Not a problem, as Product doesn't even know about Locations

The issue with this design is that it's technically possible to add the same Product to multiple locations. I don't know if that is an issue or not. One possible solution is, when a Product is added to a Location, the Location aggregate publishes an event that the Location already containing that product will handle and automatically remove that product from the collection.

You could also avoid this scenario with a technical solution, like a unique key constraint in the DB in the `LocationProducts` table.

Comment: `A Product can exist without being in any location.`. Well. That's actually a violation. Product can't exist without being in any location, it MUST have a location. That's probably me described it not well in requirements. You might create both aggregates in any time point, but condition to create product is having a Location already created.

Comment: So, in schema you proposed, we need to span transaction across two aggregates: update location's products list and save the product after it. Otherwise, using eventing, which leads to eventual consistency, we have a time when aggregates becoming not valid or inconsistent.

Comment: I've added clarification 1 about this requirement.

Comment: I don't propose using transactions across aggregates. Yes, you can use events instead. Eventual consistency is more often than not an option for developers but not an issue for the business. What would be the problem of having a Product in the system, which is in a "draft state" while it's not associated with a location? In my opinion, the information you need is already contained in the comments and answers to this question (both Udi Dahan's linked articles are very relevant). You need to choose what aggregate references the other based on what needs stronger consistency.

Comment: I proposed Location referencing Products based on your original requirements it didn't seem that Product needed to reference Location. But given the updated requirements, maybe it's better to approach it the other way around as VoiceOfUnreason proposes.

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly stated, `Product` and `Location` are two distinct aggregates. They don't control each other, and there is no problem in having `Product` holding a reference to a single `Location`. The same goes for holding a list (or even a simple counter) of `Products` inside a `Location`.

Now, suppose you are concerned about the Presentation Layer (eg. a UI or even an API),  for example, due to potential changes to a `Location`, or deletion of a `Product`. In that case, you might want to consider dispatching Domain Events and write the appropriate handlers to deal with them. You might also want to consider using CQRS, and create/refresh Query Models that will be consumed by the Presentation Layer.